# bolding part of code in MediWiki

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, mediawiki, geshi

I use `mediawiki-1.30.0` and want to bold a part of code snippet in MediaWiki. Unfortunately as it is described [here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext#Pre), *it seems* `<b></b>` does not work in `pre` tag. Also I did not find any way to bold a part of code in [SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight) extension which comes with `MediaWiki 1.21` and above.

How I can bold part of code snippet ***without*** adding a space in front of each row?

**Edit**

I tested all these three:

```
<pre>
a <strong>text</strong> inside another ...
</pre>


<pre>
a &lt;strong&gt;text&lt;/strong&gt; inside another ...
</pre>

<code>
a &lt;strong&gt;text&lt;/strong&gt; inside another ...
</code>
```

The result was the same:

```
a <strong>text</strong> inside another ...
```

Only `<code></code>` bolds text, for example for both below codes

```
<code>
a <strong>text</strong> inside another ...
and another line
</code>

<code>
a <b>text</b> inside another ...
and another line
</code>
```

the result is:

> a **text** inside another ... and another line

As you can see it processes `<b></b>`; but does not preserve `new line` characters.

Comment: you want to bold your text inside your pre tag right?

Comment: @Viira That's right.

Comment: And you can't put a space in front of each line? Using a space instead of `<pre>` allows the use of tags and wiki markup.

Comment: @astonearachnid Yes, because it is a time consumer task.

Comment: CSS: `<code style = "display: block; white-space: pre-wrap;"><b>SELECT</b> id</code>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely cannot add a space in front of each line, you could try using this: (somewhat inspired by @StanislavKralin's comment)

```
<code class="mw-code" style="display:block">
a <strong>text</strong> inside another ...
and another line
</code>
```

The `.mw-code` class mirrors the styles for `<pre>` for any element that has it. However, it also needs a `display: block` to be formatted correctly. If you didn't want to put the `display: block` on every instance, you could add the following code to the `MediaWiki:Common.css` page:

```
.mw-code{
    display: block;
}
```

Then, you would only have to add the `.mw-code` class to the `<code>` element.

**However**, this only works *if no lines are skipped and the code isn't ever indented*, this longer test case:

```
<code class="mw-code" style="display:block">
using System;

namespace <b>GDB</b>
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string argv)
        { 
            Console.Write("Hello!");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
</code>
```

makes this:
[image]
Since this is *not* a `<pre>`, the wikitext is still parsed inside, such as a space making a code block, which is why we have all the nested codeblocks.

---

***Alternatively***, you could add a space in front of each row, like so:

```
 a <strong>text</strong> inside another ...
 and another line
```

yields:

> a **text** inside another ... 
>   and another line

and always works:
[image: test case with space]

Comment: At first `<code class="mw-code" style="display:block">...</code>` worked but suddenly it does not preserve "new line"s.

Comment: @hasanghaforian At first, I only tested it with the provided test case. I have edited to include additional tests I have done.

Comment: @a stone arachnid It seems it has not a simple solution, so I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<code>` and `<b>` and then use the `<br>` tag for new lines if you want:

```
<code>
a <strong>text</strong> inside another ...
<br>and another line
</code>
```

the result is:

> a **text** inside another
>
> and another line

Comment: Adding "space" character in front of each line is much easier than adding `<br/>` at the end of lines.